# Convert symbols to html tags in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
   <?php

//Read file
$file = 'sample.txt';
$file_copy = 'sample1.txt';
$homepage = file_get_contents($file, NULL, NULL,10);
echo htmlspecialchars($homepage);

//Write file
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= "test";
file_put_contents($file_copy, $current);
$homepage = file_get_contents($file);
echo $homepage;

//search and replace
$string = 'The [[akilan]] 2 4 jumped over the lazy dog.[[prabkaran]]';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/\[\[/';
$patterns[1] = '/\]\]/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '<a href="#">';
$replacements[1] = '</a>';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

How can I get the following one using php

`if input : [[hello]]
otherwise output: <a href='hello'>hello</a>`

`if input : [[hello ok]]
otherwise output: <a href='hello_ok'>hello ok</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$string = 'The [[akilan]] 2 4 jumped over the lazy dog.[[prabkaran]] [[hello ok]]';
$pattern = "~\[\[(.*)\]\]~U";
$replace = "<a href='%s'>%s</a>";
preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,
    function($m) {
        echo "<a href='" . str_replace(' ', '_', $m[1]) . "'>" . $m[1] . "</a>\n";
    },
    $string);
```

---

### EDIT

Following up on the comment:

```
$string = 'The [[link1]] 2 4 jumped over the lazy dog.[[link2 ok]]';
$pattern = "~\[\[(.*)\]\]~U";
function convert_link($m) {
    return "<a href='" . str_replace(' ', '_', $m[1]) . "'>" . $m[1] . "</a>";
}
$string = preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,
    "convert_link",
    $string
);
echo $string;
```

Comment: i got it,like $string = 'The [[link1]] 2 4 jumped over the lazy dog.[[link2 ok]]';
$pattern = "~\[\[(.*)\]\]~U";
function convert_link($m)
{
  return "<a href='" . str_replace(' ', '_', $m[1]) . "'>" . $m[1] . "</a>\n";;
}
$string = preg_replace_callback($pattern,"convert_link",$string);
echo $string;

Comment: @user3808368 escaping the square brackets in pattern is required: `"~\[\[(.*)\]\]~U"`

Comment: ok thanks .but i want one more solution for $patterns = array ('~\[\[(.*)(\|)(.*)\]\]~U','~\[\[(.*)\]\]~U');
$replace = array ('testpluslink','test');
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replace, 'the is good [[text]] [[text|link]]');  ---->OUTPUT "testpluslink" but exceptation "text textpluslink"..plz check it

Comment: @user3808368 Use an if statement inside the function to check if `$m[1]` contains the character `|`. If it does, proceed accordingly.

Comment: my goal is replace  text(contains equilavent html) to html content...For example web page url(html content) : "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism" (text content->some part of web content,not fully):''Anarchism''' is a [[political philosophy]] that advocates [[stateless society|stateless societies]] often defined as [[self-governance|self-governed]] voluntary institutions,<ref>"ANARCHISM, a social philosophy that rejects authoritarian government and maintains that voluntary institutions are best suited to express man's natural social tendencies